# Trigger update another table

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have been trying to write a trigger function that updates the rows in the child table when the parent is changed for a while now. 
I have read Trigger procedure documentation but i have not really grasped how to build the functions.

This is what I have tried that does not work...

```
CREATE FUNCTION myschema.update_child() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
UPDATE myschema.child 
set new.number = parent.number 
FROM myschema.parent
WHERE id = "id";
RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Then the trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_child_after_update
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
   ON myschema.child
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE myschema.update_child();
```

Does anyone have some tips to give? 
Best regards

Comment: Do you want update the child table only if a record in parent is updated? Want about INSERT or DELETE? Do you want the child always be synchronized with the parent?

Comment: Due to the structure of the db i am working on, I only need to update the child table in this case

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to use the `parent` table in the body of the trigger function, because the values from the parent table are available in the function in the special variable `OLD` and `NEW`. In this case you only need `NEW`.

If you need the trigger only on update, than define a update-only trigger:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION update_child() RETURNS trigger AS
  $BODY$
BEGIN
  UPDATE child
  set number = NEW.number
  WHERE id = NEW.id;
  RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_child_after_update
AFTER UPDATE 
ON parent
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_child();
```

Comment: Thank you!! This worked just like I was hoping for, thanks for making the concept clearer for me, will read up more about it with this in mind :)

Comment: Really nice to see a real answer, and not just "read the documentation".