# PostgresSQL : Update Certain Column in Table-B After Certain Column in Table-B is Updated

Tags: postgresql, sql-function, postgresql-triggers

I have 2 table in Postgres, let's say `Category` and `Thread` with relation one-to-many

`Category`

```
id   | title | created_at | deleted_at 
-----+-------+------------+-----------
```

`Thread`

```
id   | category_id | title | created_at | deleted_at 
-----+-------------+-------+------------+-----------
```

I want to create a trigger : if i perfom soft delete in `Category` (update `deleted_at` from null to now() ), then `Thread`.`deleted_at` should get updated too.

Here is my function

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "thread_soft_delete"()
    RETURNS trigger
    AS $pg1$
    BEGIN
    UPDATE thread SET deleted_at = NOW()
    FROM "category"
    WHERE thread.category_id = "category".id;
    RETURN NULL;
    END;
    $pg1$
    VOLATILE
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And here the trigger

```
    CREATE TRIGGER category_delete
    AFTER UPDATE ON "category"
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (OLD.deleted_at IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.deleted_at)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE thread_soft_delete();
```

When i run `update "category" set deleted_at = now() WHERE id = 1;`, all `created_at` column in `thread` get updated. My expectation is only rows with `category_id` = 1 that going to update.

Please help me

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034907/trigger-update-another-table

Answer (score 0):

You need not reference the `category` table in the trigger function. Just `NEW.id()` should be fine.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "thread_soft_delete"()
RETURNS trigger
AS $pg1$
BEGIN
UPDATE thread SET deleted_at = NOW()
WHERE thread.category_id = NEW.id;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$pg1$
VOLATILE
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```